# Cheapest database option on Azure supporting Offline Data Sync / Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: azure, databases

What's the cheapest database option on Azure that can be used with [Offline Data Sync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync)? I want to run a productive app on that, but I don't expect many users and as it's only sync I don't need ultra high performance.